# HTTP Response Popup New Webpage

Tags: python, html, http, browser, popup

I want to send HTTP Response that has HTML Code that will Popup [Open new Window]
in the client browser.

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>Virus Content Detected!</head>
<body>

<h1>The File You Download Has Malicious Content!</h1>

<p> This file known as "Trojan/VB.gen", please next time
check where you download from.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: is this what you want to do?  http://www.cssscript.com/demo/minimal-modal-component-vanilla-javascript-mimodal/

Comment: Not by link that the user need to click on, I mean I send the response and in the client browser it opens new window with the HTML code that I wrote, like the annoying popup commercial pages [btw I have socket with the browser so communication with the browser is not the problem]